# Conditional iterations using outcome of first iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find a solution for the following problem.

Using the data in my pandas dataframe

[Pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQEs2.png)

```
    customer id       date  incoming  outgoing  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5
0             1 2019-01-01     500.0       0.0         0.0         0.0
1             1 2019-01-02       0.0     100.0         0.0         0.0
2             1 2019-01-03       0.0     100.0         0.0         0.0
3             1 2019-01-04       0.0     100.0         0.0         0.0
4             1 2019-01-05       0.0     150.0         0.0         0.9
5             1 2019-03-03     100.0       0.0         0.0         0.0
6             1 2019-03-04       0.0     200.0         0.0         0.0
7             1 2019-03-05      15.0       0.0         0.0         0.0
8             1 2019-03-06       0.0      50.0         0.0         0.0
9             1 2019-03-07     100.0       0.0         0.0         0.0
10            2 2019-02-01    1000.0       0.0         0.0         0.0
11            2 2019-02-03       0.0      90.0         0.0         0.0
12            2 2019-02-05       0.0      90.0         0.0         0.0
```

Given my pandas dataframe I need to find in column **incoming** the date the cumulative amount is higher than 500. This date needs to be used as input to iterate over the column outgoing as it needs to be used as the start date within a range of 3 days (date+3). Starting from the date found in the first iteration, ranging 3 days I need to aggregate the amounts in column **outgoing**, when the aggregate of outgoing / incoming => 90% i need the date when it breached the threshold

Using code from stackoverflow, I managed to workout the first part (only for one customer)

```
val = np.flatnonzero(np.isclose(CleanDF.incoming.cumsum().values, 500))[0]
CleanDF['date'].iloc[val]      # for faster access, use .iat
```

When both conditions are fullfilled I need the unique customer id and date values when the conditions are met as output in a pandas dataframe.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Please include your dataframe as text to the question. `df.to_clipboard(False)` copies the content of your dataframe as plaintext, which you can then paste to your question

Comment: Do you mind to provide the expected output? Have you ever read about [mcve](/help/mcve)?